# if variable usage bug in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I find the follow variables are handled as one variable in RF:

```
${user_name}=    Set Variable    idiot_robot
Log To Console    ${user_name}
Log To Console    ${username}
Log To Console    ${userName}
```

the print values are all the same, who can tell me if this is RF's bug?

Answer (score 3):

This is intended behaviour as stated in the official Robot Framework docs (https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html).
Quote from section 2.6.2 "Robot Framework variables, similarly as keywords, are case-insensitive, and also spaces and underscores are ignored."

Comment: thanks for your reply, I checked and that's the case, but I don't think it's a good idea to have so loose syntax